# Find lines from one file that do not appear (even partially) in another file

Tags: shell, search, match

I need a Unix shell command to find lines from file1 that do not appear **at all** in file2.
For example -

file1:

```
aaa 
bbb
```

file2:

```
aaaccc 
bb
```

Expected output:

```
bbb
```

("aaa" from file1 does appear in file2, as a part of a larger string "aaaccc").

I can't use "comm" since it only works on complete lines.
In this case I'm also looking to exclude lines in file2 that contain lines in file1 as part of larger strings, as explained above.

Note I'd prefer a fast way if exists, since my files are VERY large.

Comment: `grep -f file2 file1` works for those samples. If it's not enough, please post more exhaustive samples, please.

Comment: @JamesBrown
grep takes forever on large files. Is there a fastest way?

Comment: How _VERY large_ are your files? Do they fit in your (computer's :D) memory?

Comment: @JamesBrown Of course :) each is about 400K lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One in awk, mawk is probably the fastest so use that one:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                # process file1
    a[$0]                # hash all records to memory
    next                 # process next record
}
{                        # process file2
    for(i in a)          # for each file1 entry in memory
        if($0 ~ i)       # see if it is found in current file2 record
            delete a[i]  # and delete if found
}
END {                    # in the end
    for(i in a)          # all left from file1
        print i          # are outputted
}' file1 file2           # mind the order
```

Output:

```
bbb
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer!
However it doesn't work for me :(
I only used simple one-line awk commands in the past (like prints etc.) and they worked.
Your answer contains newline characters so it isn't recognized by my shell.

Comment: When trying to collapse it to one line, it says "syntax error"

Comment: One-liner c'n'p'd from my shell, aka _the original_: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{for(i in a)if($0 ~ i)delete a[i]}END{for(i in a)print i}' file1 file2`